# How to consume .net web service(.asmx) in android xamarin project?

Tags: android, soap, xamarin, asmx

I want to consume a web service in xamarin android application using soap format, below is my code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
TempConversionService.TempConvert tempConvert = new TempConversionService.TempConvert();                
tempConvert.Url = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
button.Text = tempConvert.CelsiusToFahrenheit("50");
```

I am trying to consume a [sample web service](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx), but every time i get 403 forbidden/ 404 Not Found error can any one please let me know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried using this service.

I added a web reference to my project, and then the following code worked

```
var service = new TempConvert.TempConvert();
var f = service.CelsiusToFahrenheit("50");
```

There's a good introduction here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/